# How to Access data outside of Function - Angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm loading in data from another file(component) and when I console it from within a function so after an event it works:

```
  updateSub(data) {
  console.log('attempting to print the subsid array' + 
  this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames)
  }
```

When I try to call out outside of this and outside of scope but within my ngOnit 
it consoles empty:

```
console.log('attempting to print the subsid array initially' + 
this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames)
```

All of the code is included within my ngOnit.
I have also included engagementService in my constructor, thats how i am accessing it:

```
 export class EngagementFilterComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, public engagementService:
 EngagementService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {

 console.log('attempting to print the subsid array initially' + 
 this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames)

 } 
 }
```

In Engagement service I make the http call like so:

```
    organizationSubsidiaries(sfid: string) {
    const url = `${this.baseURL}/${ENDPOINTS.organizations}/${this.organization.id}/${ENDPOINTS.subsidiaries}`;
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Then when the browser is loaded it is called like such and i create the array I want from the response:

```
        this.organizationSubsidiaries(id)
      .subscribe(data => {

        let subsidiaryNames = []
        data.forEach(sub => {
          console.log(sub.SubsidiaryName)
          subsidiaryNames.push(sub.SubsidiaryName)
        })
        subsidiaryNames = subsidiaryNames.filter(this.onlyUnique);
        this.orgSubSidNames = subsidiaryNames;
        console.log('data from subsidiaries' + JSON.stringify(this.orgSubSidNames))

      });
```

So an example of another call using observables (what I might be missing) is here:

```
    allEngagementAreas(): Observable<IBaseEngagement[]> {
    const url = `${this.baseURL}/${ENDPOINTS.engagementAreas}`;
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json() as IBaseEngagement[]);
  }
```

The array I have I want to display in the UI.

What can I do?

Comment: can you post your ngOnInit method?

Comment: yes i'll do it now

Comment: Is data coming from ajax or http call?

Comment: It's a http call

Comment: Oh so it's not going to just be there is it, because it reads the line before the data exists, so how would i then use the data and assign it?

Comment: Im using the array to display the names on a drop down menu in the UI

Comment: u need to use Observable subscribe in order to achive your functionality. If you post content of engagementService then we can help you

Comment: Okay I've added it, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a way to let your component know when the API call is complete. To do this, you can return an observable from the service and subscribe it in the component.

For example, in your service, you can have:

```
public getOrgSubsidiaries(id) {
    return this.organizationSubsidiaries(id).map(data => {
        let subsdiaryNames = [];
        // your logic
        return subsdiaryNames;
    });
}
```

Then, inside your component, you can do:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.engagementService.getOrgSubsidiaries(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.orgSubsidiaries = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesnt recognise 'id' in the component which is trying to subscribe to the first one

Comment: Then you can just get rid of the parameter and call the method directly, and use the id in the service.

Comment: the .map doesnt return anything by the way, .subscribe worked as previously but .map doesnt console anything

Comment: Sure but it's exactly the same just with your function being used